# Getting the real dimensions of an image with titanium

Tags: android, ios, titanium

I'm trying to create a cross-platform app.

So I have an image 1000x200 and I want to position it as image on background.

I try to calculate a real image size, to get it perfect on each screen. Because titanium resizes images and scales them in some magic way...

`menuBottomImageView.toImage().width` works fine on iOS and I get 1000px, but on android I get not the real size, only the displayed size and that's not what I need.

Is there a way to get the real dimensions of a file for both systems?

Answer (score 0):

for Android there is no better method, if you use getWidth() method, it will give createImageView()'s width, mentioned in the object. best one is your method menuBottomImageView.toImage().width .

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Android set up to test it, but on iOS I've discovered you can use:

```
var imgBlob = menuBottomImageView.toBlob(),
    imgWidth = imgBlob.width,
    imgHeight = imgBlob.height;
```

Using `toBlob()` is also *much* faster than using `toImage()`. According to the docs this is supported on Android, but then the docs say lots of things that don't always work out.

Answer (score 0):

If the controller you are asking for `toImage()` is added and loaded on window then only it will give you proper size.